# Github Project Pages cannot be shown

Tags: github

1. I hosted an app on my user page http://github.com/tianshuo/tianshuo.github.com/trello , this is shown on http://tianshuo.gihub.com/trello/
2. People started to clone my user page, so I made a new repository `trello` to put my app
3. I put my files into the repository branch `gh-pages` and delete the directory from my user page
4. Github tells me my pages are updated
5. I go to http://tianshuo.github.com/trello/ and find 404 error
6. I update again, Github again tells me my pages are updated
7. Still 404

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong.

Edit: using real links

Comment: Can you link your repository, so we can have a look at it? Did you push the gh-pages branch to github? http://user.github.com/app/ should work. If you pushed gh-pages the first time, it may take some minutes.

Comment: Ok, I got the bug, it was an uppercase problem - I used `Trello` instead of `trello`

Comment: Thanks for this, I just realized this was the problem I'm having too after importing another blog...

Comment: This is a related question; can anyone answer it?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25396383/does-a-folder-in-my-user-site-conflict-with-a-project-site