# Does a folder in my user site conflict with a project site?

Tags: github, hosting

[GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/) allows each user to have one **User Site** (maybe a home page) and unlimited **Project Sites**.

When you set up your **User Site**, you *must* name the repo `[username].github.io` (where `[username]` is your GitHub username), and the URL is by default:

```
http://[username].github.io/
```

Any changes made to the `master` branch in your `[username].github.io` repo are uploaded to your User Site.

When you set up a **Project Site**, you can name the repo anything you want (let's call it `[projname]`). The URL is by default:

```
http://[username].github.io/[projname]
```

Any changes made to the `gh-pages` branch in your `[projname]` repo are uploaded to the Project Site.

**My question is, what if in your User Site repository, you coincidentally have a folder that has the same name as your Project Site repository?**

For example, say you have a file `index.html` inside a folder `temp/` in your User Site repo `bob.github.io`. Then that page would be hosted online at

```
http://bob.github.io/temp/index.html
```

Now say you create a Project Site with repo name `temp`. In that repo, you have a file called `index.html`. Then when you push it to the`gh-pages` branch, would it be hosted online at

```
http://bob.github.io/temp/index.html
```

?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11259305/github-project-pages-cannot-be-shown

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just did the experiment of naming a new repo with the same name as a subfolder in my user site repo:

As a result the new repo took precedence over my personal site.

Answer (score 7):

Github support response:

Yes, they would conflict. The url for Project sites will be username.github.io/project, and the url for a folder in a user or organization site would be username.github.io/project.

I would recommend that you either rename the directory or the repository name.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "conflict"? If I have `file1.txt` in my User site `username.github.io/folder/file1.txt` and `file2.txt` in a Project `folder` site `username.github.io/folder/file2.txt` will they both be accessible at the corresponding URLs?

Comment: To conflict they would have to be the same name and end up resolving to the same url.

Comment: Stumbled into this, and thought I could just disable publishing on the project repo, resolving the conflict that way, but that turns out that was not enough!

Answer (score 0):

I also did a test keeping "mydocs" as one project repo (public activated with GH pages) and a directory "mydocs" in my .github.io repo. I just wanted to make sure if content is merged (appears in addition to project repo content)in the /mydocs directory. But it does not happen. It honours the repo content only, there is no merging of main site repo content under the / context.